# How many concurrent connections can GrizzlyHttpServer handle?

Tags: spring, rest, httpserver, grizzly

I'm looking after a Spring rest application that uses GrizzlyHttpServer as HTTP server. I need to know what's the default maximum number of concurrent connections that this server can handle?

Comment: There is no such a limit in Grizzly.
Are you looking for a way to limit the max number of concurrent connections?

Comment: No, I don't want to limit them. Just wondering if there's a limit, I couldn't find any documentation regarding that.

Comment: no, there are no limits. It will try to handle as much as OS can.